# How to ignore where condition when loading mapped object jpa

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to two JPA entities as given bellow

```
@Where( clause = "is_deleted = 0" )
public class Request{
    @OneToOne( mappedBy = "request",
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
    private RequestRegistartion requestRegistartion;
}


public class RequestRegistartion {
    @OneToOne
    @NotNull
    private Request request;
}
```

when I am loading `RequestRegistartion` from `RequestRegistartionRepository` i need to load all mapped `Request` even Requests `is_deleted=1`.
**Is there a way to ignore where condition only for `RequestRegistartionRepository` quarries**

Comment: I would be happy if you upvote my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can only do one of the following and you cannot mix them.

- **You let hibernate hide the soft deleted entities from the application.**

  Since you have taken this approach, `@Where( clause = "is_deleted = 0" )`, as far as hibernate is concerned, they are dead and it will never bring them back.

  Exception is where you write native sql query, select the columns and Map it yourself. As far as hibernate is concerned, they are not managed.
- **You do not let hibernate treat the soft deleted entities as deleted and application take cares of it**

  As far as hibernate is concerned, your soft delete is an update of entity, it will bring all entities.

  So incases where you don't want them, either you override the spring data repository methods to provide a query `@Query("select e from Request r where r. isDeleted =true")` or you retrieve everything and then filter in memory

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. As described on your first point if write a native query on RequestRegistartionRepository, I still have to write the mapping as well right?

Comment: Yes. You have to do that